# shortcode doesn't work when I'm getting content from wp rest api call

Tags: php, wordpress, rest, shortcode, visual-composer

I'm trying to get the content of a custom post type called event using wp rest api . everything works fine but I used Wp Backery page builder for creating contents in my event post type and the problem is I'm getting shortcodes without parsing and they are in plain text .

Can anybody help me with this, please?

I've tried some of answers in similar questions like using `do_shortcode()` function and trying to call 
`apply_filters( 'the_content' , get_the_content())`
but none of them work for me

here is my rest-api codes:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init' , 'wt_rest_api');

function wt_rest_api(){
    register_rest_route('wtrest','events',array(
            'methods'   => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
            'callback'  => 'wtEventResults'
        )); 
}

function wtEventResults($data){
    $events = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post__in'  => array( (int)$data['id'] )
        ]);

    $eventsResults = [];

    while($events->have_posts()){
        $events->the_post();

        array_push($eventsResults , [
            'content'   => apply_filters( 'the_content' , get_the_content())
            ]);
    }

    return $eventsResults;

}
```

I'm getting the result but the shortcodes aren't parsing and their just plain text .
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to [@muka.gergely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2316540/muka-gergely) I've found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39534377/11432102).

final code that worked for me is here:

```
add_action( 'rest_api_init' , 'wt_rest_api');

function wt_rest_api(){
    register_rest_route('wtrest','events',array(
            'methods'   => WP_REST_SERVER::READABLE,
            'callback'  => 'wtEventResults'
        )); 
}


function wtEventResults($data){
    WPBMap::addAllMappedShortcodes(); // This does all the work

    $events = new WP_Query([
        'post_type' => 'event',
        'post__in'  => array( (int)$data['id'] )
        ]);

    $eventsResults = [];

    while($events->have_posts()){
        $events->the_post();


        array_push($eventsResults , [
                'content'   => apply_filters( 'the_content' ,  get_the_content() )
            ]);
    }

    return $eventsResults;

}
```

Hope it saves you some time

Answer (score -1):

For anyone who might be interested, this worked for me

```
apply_filters('the_content', $content);
```

It's also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007573/how-to-load-visual-composer-during-using-ajax-in-wordpress)